# Responses Training Kit Exam 70-461

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm studying for exam 70-461. The book is the question:

```
1. Suppose you want to rename the result attribute phone to phone number. Here’s an attempt to alias the attribute with the identifier phone number without delimiters.

SELECT S.shipperid, companyname, phone AS phone number FROM Sales.Shippers AS S;
```

My answer would be:

```
SELECT S.shipperid, companyname, phone AS PhoneNumber FROM Sales.Shippers AS S;
```

The answer is so simple? Where will I can responses Training Kit 70-461?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to keep the alias name inside Square Brackets to show the phone number with space.

```
SELECT S.shipperid, companyname, phone AS [phone number] FROM Sales.Shippers AS S
```

OR

```
SELECT S.shipperid, companyname, phone AS 'phone number' FROM Sales.Shippers AS S
```

Comment: Question say: "without delimiters". how to do? or am I wrong on the Interpretation of the question?

Comment: @mtsys - Delimiter is used to separate two things i dono what you are trying to mean here!!